# Combining multiple Android Sensors with helper Classes

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, sensormanager

I am trying to build an application that would allow me to retrieve data from multiple sensors simultaneously. I still have not figured out how I will get there, so I started by implementing a SensorObject class for a structured layout.

This sensorobject implements the SensorEventListener together with the usual onaccuracychanged and onsensorchanged methods.I have left both methods empty for now since this class is inherited.
I also implemented OnResume method like so:

```
    public void OnResume() {
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
```

Successively I implemented an accelerometer object that extends the sensor object. Substantially, it does stuff in the onSensor Changed.

My main questions lie here
1) When in the activity, I am never getting a result from the accelerometer object, since it only enters the 'onSensorChanged' method until **AFTER the below code has been executed**:

```
    AccelerometerObject ao =  new AccelerometerObject(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, this);
    ao.OnResume();

    txtAccelerometerData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAccelerometerData);
    txtAccelerometerData.setText(ao.toString());
```

Why isn't it accessing the sensor data immediately but proceeding sequentially? The object still has no values since the onresume method hasnt been accessed. Will i need to use seperate threads? Efficiency is not that important, all I need is valid data for experimentation.

2) is it possible to implement multiple simultaneous sensors using the above approach?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the AccelerometerObject as requested.

```
public class AccelerometerObject extends SensorObject {

public float[] values;

public AccelerometerObject(int sensorType, Context _Context) {
    super(sensorType, _Context);
}   

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    AccelerometerValues = event.values;
    onPause();
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    if (values != null) {
        return "X is " + values[0]
                + ", Y is " + values[1]
                + " and Z is "
                + values[2]);
    } else
        return "N/A";
}
```

}

Comment: I am not sure exactly the reasoning behind your implementation. You can register all the Sensors you would like and receive callbacks when values change.

Comment: My main objective here is that of retrieving data from multiple sensors at the same time. 
However it seems i have 2 issues
1) I cannot retrieve the data simultaneously 
2) When implementing helper classes ( to avoid messy code) its only accessing the sensors after the above code executes (display info in textbox)

Comment: Can you show complete code of AccelerometerObject class?

Comment: Are you developing using eclipse?

Comment: @Salauyou, code uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just uploaded an eclipse project here: http://cyrixmorten.net/CA-Project.zip

The project has been used to gather data for a course in Context Awareness.

It demonstrates getting sensor values from

- Accelerometer
- Gyroscope
- Orientation
- GPS

In the implementation I have implemented a Service for each sensor. This is perhaps unnecessarily complex but we needed the data gathering to continue in the background even when not in focus.

Edit:

By the way all the *ResultReceiver objects merely acts as glue between the Activity and the Service they represent. The *ResultReceiver object receive the sensor events and translate them into a custom interface which is then used by the MainActivity.

I could imaging that part could lead to confusion but I just do not like messing with a lot of different Bundles and Strings in my Activities when I can get exact values through an interface - merely a design choice for personal protection against typos I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, I will have a look at it and let you know.

Comment: No problem :) hope it is helpful

Comment: Hi, I abandoned the approach completely and threw all the sensors in one class since it was becoming really complicated but your solution pointed out what was missing:

1) Your sensor services, which I call objects have to extend 'Service' which I was not doing.
2) Result receivers are required to pass information accordingly.
3) The use of handlers is required

As I said, I have abandoned the approach but your contribution will lead anyone to the proper answer. Hence I am marking it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: P.S. To get all sensors working simultaneously I set up event listeners for each sensors, and in a separate thread I did a loop to get data from each sensor and save it.

Comment: Happy to hear that, although I do believe that 1) you do not need to set up a separate thread to do so and 2) the values should not be pooled but rather pushed by the sensor and grabbed by the activity, as is done in my example code if you run it an push the 'train me' button. However, you got it working as you would like and that is nonetheless the goal here :) happy coding

Comment: I fully agree with what you say. However I could not get the sensors to work at all (simultaneously) and time is not on my side.
When my research will be concluded however, I will dedicate time to revisiting the code. Cheers!

Comment: Yes unfortunately my server had its harddisk replaced. I can point you to another similar project once I get to my pc tomorrow.

Comment: congrats on your new PC